# Method of characteristics and explicit formula for an IBVP for the transport equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, hyperbolic-pde

Let us assume $c:(0,1) \to (\epsilon,+\infty)$ and consider the PDE
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t+c(x)u_x = 0, \\
u(0,x) = g(x) \\
u(t,0) = f(t)
\end{cases} \qquad (t,x) \in (0,T)\times(0,1) \label{1}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
Suppose also that the ODE
$$\dot x(t) = c(x(t)), \quad x(0) = x_0$$ has a unique solution $x \in W^{1,\infty}(0,T)$.

How can we write down explicitly a solution formula for \eqref{1} using the method of characteristics?

I'm guessing that the explicit solution should be  $$
   u(t,x) = \begin{cases}
    g(\beta^{-1}(\beta(x)-t)), \ & (t,x) \in (0,T)\times (0,1), \ t \le \beta(x), \\
    f((t-\beta(x)),  & (t,x) \in (0,T)\times (0,1), \ t > \beta(x);
    \end{cases}
$$ with $\beta(x) = \int_0^x \frac{dy}{c(y)}$. How can we rigorously prove this with the assumptions given above?

Comment: What do you want to prove ? Can't you just substitute and check ?